# Sending data to moisture meter through USB Host Shield from Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial, arduino-ide

Im working on a moisture meter that has RS232 output with integrated PL2303 to USB cable.

I can read 0x10 from and send 0x20 to the meter to get the measurement data on Python from PC.

But with Arduino and the shield, i cant send 0x20 to meter. No HEX data response because rcode from SndData function gives zero

Below is the arduino source code:

```
/* Arduino terminal for PL2303 USB to serial converter and DealeXtreme GPRS modem. */
/* USB support */
#include <usbhub.h>

/* CDC support */
#include <cdcacm.h>

#include <cdcprolific.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude#include <spi4teensy3.h>

#endif#include <SPI.h>

class PLAsyncOper: public CDCAsyncOper {
  public: uint8_t OnInit(ACM * pacm);
};

uint8_t PLAsyncOper::OnInit(ACM * pacm) {
  uint8_t rcode;

  // Set DTR = 1
  rcode = pacm -> SetControlLineState(1);

  if (rcode) {
    ErrorMessage < uint8_t > (PSTR("SetControlLineState"), rcode);
    return rcode;
  }

  LINE_CODING lc;
  lc.dwDTERate = 2400;
  lc.bCharFormat = 0;
  lc.bParityType = 0;
  lc.bDataBits = 8;

  rcode = pacm -> SetLineCoding( & lc);

  if (rcode)
    ErrorMessage < uint8_t > (PSTR("SetLineCoding"), rcode);

  return rcode;
}
USB Usb;
//USBHub     Hub(&Usb);
PLAsyncOper AsyncOper;
PL2303 Pl( & Usb, & AsyncOper);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(2400);
  #if!defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
  #endif
  Serial.println("Start");

  if (Usb.Init() == -1)
    Serial.println("OSCOKIRQ failed to assert");

  delay(200);
}

void loop() {
  Usb.Task();

  if (Usb.getUsbTaskState() == USB_STATE_RUNNING) {
    uint8_t rcode;

    /* reading the converter */
    /* buffer size must be greater or equal to max.packet size */
    /* it it set to 64 (largest possible max.packet size) here, can be tuned down
    for particular endpoint */
    uint8_t buf[64];
    uint16_t rcvd = 64;

    rcode = Pl.RcvData( & rcvd, buf);
    if (rcode && rcode != hrNAK)
      ErrorMessage < uint8_t > (PSTR("Ret"), rcode);

      if (rcvd) { //more than zero bytes received
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
            Serial.print(" ");
        }

        if (rcvd == 1) {
          Serial.println("Size = 1");
          Serial.print("HEX from device: ");
          Serial.println(buf[0], HEX);
          //Confirm if we got 0x10 response from device
          if (buf[0] == 0x10) {
            Serial.println("Got data ready to send response from device ");
            //Send 0x20 to device
            uint8_t rq = 0x20;
            rcode = Pl.SndData(1, &rq);
            
            if (rcode) {
                ErrorMessage < uint8_t > (PSTR("SndData"), rcode);
                Serial.print("HEX from user: ");
                Serial.println(rcode, HEX);
            }
          }
        } else {
          Serial.println("Size > 1");
          Serial.println(sizeof(buf));
          for (uint16_t i = 0; i < rcvd; i++) {
            Serial.print(buf[i], HEX);
            Serial.print(" ");
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The python script for testing on PC that works well

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM17', 2400)

# Check if serial is available then print what is read
if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')
    # Make the handshake Xon/Xoff
    #ser.write(b'\x11')
    # Make the handshake RTS/CTS
    #ser.setRTS(True)
    # Setup flow control to RTS/CTS
    #ser.setRTS(True)
    while True:
        # Read bytes from serial
        data = ser.read()
        # Print what is read
        print(data.hex)
        # Check if we get 0x10
        if data == b'\x10':
            # Send 0x20
            ser.write(b'\x20')
            # Send 0x20 as uint8
            #ser.write(bytes([0x20]))
            # Send 32 as uint8
            #ser.write(bytes([32]))
            # Then check if we got data, if so print it
            #data = ser.read()
            #print(data)
            if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            #    print(ser.read())
                # Convert to hex
            #    print(ser.read().hex())
                print("Got data")
            else:
                print("No data")
    else:
        print('serial not available')
```

The meter in use

[image]

Please help. Thank you.